# How to skip the afterEach hook if the current test case fails and continue to run the next test case after?

Tags: mocha.js

```
describe("Test1", function() {
  before("at the start", function() {
   console.log("AT the begining of the test case");
   setup();
  }

  beforeEach("before test case", function() {
   console.log("at the begining of the test case");
   testsetup();
  }

  afterEach("at the end of test case", function() {
   console.log("at the end of test case");
   cleanup();
  }

  after("at the end of test", function() {
   console.log("at the end of test");
   commoncleanup();
  }

  it("test case1", function() {
   var retval = sum(2,5);
   assert.equal(retval, "then sum is 5");
  }

  it("test case2", function() {
   var retval = sum(5,5);
   assert.equal(retval, "the sum is 10");
  }
});
```

If the `beforeEach` code fails or throws error, it continues the test case1 and afterEach hook. but I want if `beforeEach` fails it should skip the test case1 and `afterEach` hook, then continue to run the test case2 and `afterEach` hook. I mean if any hook fails it should skip the current test case and continue to run the next test cases.
I want the expected output to be:

```
Test1
AT the beginning of the test case
before test case
x beforeEach hook fails
before test case
test case2 
at the end of test case
at the end of test
1 passing (8ms)
1 failing (0ms)
```

please help me to find solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `this.currentTest.state` (not sure when this was introduced):

```
afterEach(function() {
  if (this.currentTest.state == 'failed') {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: This answer does not do what the OP asked. The issue the OP has is that if a failure occurs in a hook, then Mocha will not call any of the callbacks passed to `it`. In effect, the test suite stops as soon as there is an error in a hook. The OP wants to be able to have Mocha continue running tests even if the hooks fail. Checking `this.currentTest.state` does not accomplish this goal.

Answer (score 1):

There's no flag to use to get what you want. Mocha is designed so that an error in any of the hooks terminates testing right away. (After an error in a hook, Mocha will continue running the `afterEach`, and `after` hooks but won't continue running tests.)

One way to do what you want would be to:

1. Write your `beforeEach` so that it records whether the setup is successful or not.
2. Write your test to check whether the test setup is correctly set and fail if it is not.
3. Write your `afterEach` so that it does not fail if the test setup was not properly set.

The details of how to do this really depend on your application but it could look like this:

```
describe("Test1", function() {
    var set = false; // Variable indicating whether our setup is set or not.

    beforeEach("before test case", function() {
        set = testsetup();
    });
    afterEach("at the end of test case", function() {
        if (set)
            cleanup();
    });
    it("test case1", function() {
        assert.true(set, "we have a proper setup");
        // whatever tests
    });

    it("test case2", function() {
        assert.true(set, "we have a proper setup");
        // whatever tests
    });
});
```

In the code above `assert` is some assertion library you'd use for testing, `testsetup` is a function that creates what needs to be created for a test and succeeds or fails atomically (i.e. it does not leave garbage around if it fails), and `cleanup` is a cleanup routine.

This way if the setup fails only for one test, then only this test will fail.